# Consensus codon optimization by organism

Tags: dna, bioinformatics, molecular-genetics

Does a public database exist that contains this information? I'm trying to make a simple gene annotation program that will let me input a DNA sequence and then optimize it based on one of these tables using the *E. coli* preferences, for example.

Comment: This sounds like http://www.jcat.de/

Comment: That tool is pretty much what I was going for. Thank you.

Comment: http://helixweb.nih.gov/dnaworks/ also has this functionality. It also accepts information from the Codon Usage Database. However, I'll love to see any improvements in the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [Codon Usage Database](http://www.kazusa.or.jp/codon/) at Kazusa. You can search by organism. The database contains 35,799 organisms and compiled from 3,027,973 complete protein coding genes (CDS's), but last updated in 2007.

Comment: This kind of database is what I was looking for in terms of access. JCat seems like a good tool to do the work for me, but I'd like to try it myself using this database.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of softwares doing that kind of functionality. A 2007 open access review lists >30 such softwares http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17882154. However, No correlation between 'most common' codon and recombinant protein expression yield. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21102527. Thus, those >30 softwares are pointless.

Comment: The second conclusion is interesting. I would have thought perhaps it would make a difference when using microbes as bioreactors and the only quantifiable trait that matters is the yield.